# jQuery function : .focus() wrongly applied instead of .click()

Tags: jquery, click, focus

I made a small jQuery function to show/hide a subnav on both focus and click, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Here is the HTML code :

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="http://foo.com">Foo</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>(...)</li>
</ul>
```

And here is the jQuery function :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  subnavDisplay('#nav > li > a');
});

var subnavDisplay = function(selector){
  if(!$(selector).length) return;

  $(selector).focus(function() {
    console.log('focus');
    $(this).parent().addClass('is_opened').siblings().removeClass('is_opened');
  });

  $(selector).click(function(e) {
    console.log('click');
    if($(this).parent('is_opened').length === 0) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().addClass('is_opened').siblings().removeClass('is_opened');
    }
  });
};
```

[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NenVw/12/)

When I activate the link to display the subnav, the focus function is always played, and the click one never.
Do you know why ?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: bind two events when u going to trigger for one selector

Answer (score 0):

When you use `alert`, it has the tendancy to break things. In this case, you may have focussed on the element but you are no longer clicking it.

I replaced `alert` with `console.log` and I'm successfully getting both events.

Comment: Not here under chrome win7

Comment: @roasted I suspect that's because it doesn't support the `focus` event for `<a>` elements, instead keeping it for `<input>` and similar.

Comment: Ya, we need to specify tabindex attribute

Comment: That'd work. I also tested adding `<input/>` before it, and pressing Tab to focus the link, and that worked (WARNING: Will give an endless loop of "focus" alerts if you don't change to `console.log`!)

Comment: Usually, I use `console.log()` but I just replaced it by an `alert()` for the jsFiddle demo. I get the same behaviour with both `alert()` and `console.log()`

Answer (score 0):

Not all element can be focused by default. To get this behaviour, you have to add attribute `tabindex` to specific element as `<a>` tag:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NenVw/16/)

```
$('#nav > li > a').attr('tabindex',-1);
```

But as explain by Kolink, using alert inside focus callback function will break some thing, so use console.log() instead to check event is triggered.

Comment: The OP's question states that he is successfully getting the `focus` event, but not the click one, so this wasn't the main problem. Our combined answers cover the whole thing ^_^

Comment: I am a little bit surprised by the result of your demo. The links (`<a>` elements) can be focused by default, so I doesn't understand why the `tabindex` attribute is required.

Comment: Which browser are you using? In chrome, without specify tabindex, <a> cannot be focused